# SQL : find missing value

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables ID, STAT and STATVALUE with data like this in STATVALUE =>

```
ID STAT VALUE
1  10   50
1  11   60
2  10   20
2  11   30
2  12   40
3  10   10
3  11   10
3  12   10
```

I would like to retrieve the missing STAT with a result set like :

```
10 1 
11 1 
12 0
```

In this case, it would be 12 because there is no STAT=12 for ID=1

I tried with EXISTS and sub-selects but could not success
Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the approach.  Generate all combinations of `id` and `stat`.  Then figure out which ones you don't have.  The first uses a `cross join`.  And, the following query uses `left join` for the second part:

```
select i.id, s.stat
from id i cross join
     stat s left join
     statvalue sv
     on sv.id = i.id and sv.stat = s.stat
where sv.id is null;
```

If you only have one table, you can also do this:

```
select i.id, s.stat
from (select distinct id from statvalue) i cross join
     (select distinct stat from statvalue) s left join
     statvalue sv
     on sv.id = i.id and sv.stat = s.stat
where sv.id is null;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually it doesn't work because it gives me all values from STAT (even not in STATVALUE for the IDs) because of the cross join but I will continue to search in this direction

Comment: In that case, use the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

Putting 2 tables in a FROM clause will by default result in a crossjoin of all records. We only need a where clause to find the missing combinations in STATVALUE

```
select i.id, s.stat
from id i, stat s
where not exists (select 1 from statvalue sv where sv.id = i.id and sv.stat = s.stat)
```

Comment: I had tested things like this but it doesn't work because there is always a line which exists with other stats and it returns nothing...